# x86_64 SSE alignment : differences between GCC and Clang

Tags: c, alignment, clang, sse, simd

I have a large codebase using SSE intrinsics extensively, that has been developped under GCC for the x86_64 platform only. There are a lot of `__m128` and `float[4]` allocated on the stack, which are always aligned to 16-byte when compiling with GCC on x86_64.

We are testing clang, and it crashes on misaligned SSE loads and stores, on the stack variables.

It seems I can fix all errors one by one by us `__attribute__ ((aligned(16)))`

Is there any way to force clang to align all variables to 16 bytes globally? I can't find any in the documentation.

Comment: When gcc can see code doing SIMD loads/stores to local arrays, it chooses to align the target arrays.  (Saving you from your mistake of not specifying alignment yourself).  Also, the x86-64 SysV ABI specifies that local or global arrays of at least 16 bytes, and all VLAs, get 16-byte alignment (3.1.2 Aggregates and Unions), so IDK why clang isn't doing that.  Maybe not targeting Linux / OS X, or maybe LLVM thinks the ABI is overstepping its bounds specifying alignment for locals.

Answer (score 4):

`__m128` local variables should be 16 byte aligned with any compiler and should not need any additional work. `float[4]` only has 4 byte alignment so you will need to add suitable directives for these. Most people use a macro for this, e.g.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  // MSVC...
  #define ALIGN(n) declspec(align(n))
#else
  // the civilised world...
  #define ALIGN(n) __attribute__ ((aligned(n)))
#endif
```

and then declare variables as e.g.:

```
ALIGN(16) float[4] my_floats;
```

Comment: In portable C11, `#include <stdalign.h>` and use `alignas(16) float arr[4];`  (As a bonus, exactly the same syntax will compile as C++.)